# Can Floette Eternal be obtained by glitches or hack-only?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've seen many hackers with AZ's Floette, but I was told there is a glitch you can perform to obtain it. Is that true, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, it isn't possible.

There is no known way to obtain Eternal Flower Floette through glitches alone. Eternal Floette is a never-released event Pokemon and can only be obtained through hacking.